# Which approach of search is feasible (elastic search + mongoDB) or mongoDB text indexes

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, meanjs

In my project I have to implement text search and and have to choose a feasible 
approach among the two that are :-

1. **Synchronising MongoDB database with ElasticSearch.**
2. **MongoDB's own text indexes that has Elastic Search like text searching
   capabilities.**

I have gone through many articles that provide the pros of each of the cases but haven't found any relevant document that provides comparison between the two approaches and which approach is better than the other or what are the limitation for a specific approach.

**Note:- I am using Node.js with express.js.**

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is a general purpose database, Elasticsearch is a distributed text search engine backed by Lucene. You can store data in MongoDB and use Elasticsearch exclusively for its' full-text search capabilities. According to your use case, you can only send a subset of the mongo data fields to elastic.

1. Synchronization of mongodb with Elasticsearch can be done with [mongoosastic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoosastic). You can solve data safety concern by persisting in mongo and speed up your search by using elasticsearch. Also can use python script using elasticsearch.py package to sync mongo and elasticsearch.
2. Mongodb search is very slow as compared to elasticsearch. Also indexing in mongodb takes up more time and more resources.